# Javascript to run a function when input focus

Tags: javascript

What is the code to run a function, say called "myfunction" when a user clicks within an input box (focus).

I have seen examples in jquery but I cant see how to do it with straight javascript.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onfocus.asp

Comment: The non-w3fools docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onfocus Also, for something like `element.addEventListener`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/focus_(event)

Comment: Erm, SO kinda derped on my link and the comment *just* ran over the editing time: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/focus_%28event%29

Comment: @Kiyura: anything wrong with **that particular page**? Or you just like calling someone fools without any reasons?

Comment: @zerkms Except describing only the most ancient way of assigning an event handler (so that only a single handler may be attached) and being way wrong with that IE-centric 'The onfocus attribute can be used within ALL HTML elements...'?

Comment: @raina77ow: I see **exactly the same** on the mozilla page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onfocus `element.onfocus = event handling code` vs `object.onfocus=function(){SomeJavaScriptCode}` on w3schools. So? Any **real** differences?

Comment: @zerkms So you don't see this line: "Opposite to MSIE, which almost all kinds of elements receive focus event, almost all kinds of elements on Gecko browsers do NOT work with this event".

Comment: @raina77ow: I see it. How is it related to "only the most ancient way of assigning an event handler" if they both demonstrate **the same** way of assigning handlers?

Comment: @zerkms With all due respect, I fail to understand how shortcoming of one doc justifies the same quality of another one. You've asked what's wrong with that page - and somehow I think I answered that.

Comment: @raina77ow: your original explanation makes no sense "Except describing only the most ancient way of assigning an event handler (so that only a single handler may be attached)", because both of them demonstrate the same way of doing that, and it implies having only one handler attached **on both pages**. So, the only difference is in that single line that isn't accurate on w3schools, though the code examples are pretty correct. And even more - in the context of the question - they are identical, because the question is about **INPUTS**. Yes, context makes sense.

Comment: Indeed, I don't think w3schools is ideal, but what makes me sick is when people blame someone without real reasons. And in the context of the current question - there is no such reason.

Comment: @zerkms - w3schools is much better than it used to be as far as accuracy of information, but historically it had a lot of problems. I wouldn't hold its past against it, but what I don't like is that it implies an association with the w3c that it doesn't actually have, and _it charges money for useless certifications_ - both of which fall within the category of "fraud" as far as I'm concerned. I'm not as rabidly against them as these guys: http://w3fools.com/ - but still I wouldn't recommend them.

Comment: @nnnnnn: "I don't like they have business and offer some certifications" is a fantastic explanation for technical community!

Comment: @zerkms I got your point, but as I doubt that single page will answer the OP's needs, I have to look at resource as whole. And, sadly, while w3schools's quality has improved indeed, it's still no match for MDN (and MSDN), in my opinion.

Comment: @raina77ow: the question is - "how do I handle onfocus event in pure js?" and that page perfectly answers it (whether you like it or not).

Comment: @zerkms Then why the OP asks _us_ about what answer is the best, how do you think?

Comment: @raina77ow: because OP isn't experienced enough. You see, MDN's magic-and-the-best-correct-page-ever didn't help him either. Now you realize that the pages are both *useless*? Now let's start blaming MDN that it's bad because not every "developer" may understand it.

Comment: @zerkms You just don't get it, I'm afraid. It's exactly because the OP lacks experience, he (in my opinion) better stay with more solid tutorials and documentation sites - because the single page won't be enough for him. And if you really think that w3schools as _whole_ can be as helpful as MDN, well... it's your choice. )

Comment: @raina77ow: come on, because of the lack of experience he won't even notice that line. What he needs is just some easy to understand solution, that's it. "And if you really think that w3schools as whole can be as helpful as MDN" -- I didn't say that. If you scroll up and read the whole discussion you'll see that I emphasized "particular page" for this particular question.

Comment: @JamesWillson which ever answer depends on what your requirements are - they each have their benefits. I know which one I'd go for, but then that's not for me to say ;) #1 is simple/lightweight so is good if you want a small js footprint, but doesn't support IE8 and below #2 is ok if you are working on a lone small project plus it is easy to understand #3 is bulky and complicated but is flexible and should cover most situations thrown at it.

Comment: @zerkms - If all they did was provide technical references in exchange for advertising revenue I would have no problem with it. What I'm saying is I won't support a site that is willing to take people's money in exchange for a _worthless_ certification. In providing that "service" they are actively duping people for financial gain, especially when they've deliberately set up their site to make it seem like they have w3c endorsement when they don't. I don't think a technical community should just ignore such dodgy business practices.

Answer (score 3):

use the onfocus attribute

```
<input type="text" onfocus="someFunc()">

<script>
  function someFunc(){

  }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have to inline the JS event attach? )

Comment: Just as a future note: Whilst this is an easy method - and fine for small projects - it is not recommended for quite a few different reasons. 1) you are mixing code and markup which is bad for future-proofing and extensibility 2) attaching js directly as an element's attribute is more prone to memory leaks 3) you can only apply one event listener per event type 4) bad for mark-up readability 5) as part of XSS protection you should be stripping all these kind of attributes from your markup 6) event management and prevention is much more of a headache from the code side.

Comment: @pebbl: the 5th item about XSS is 100% irrelevant here, you don't even know there if this html/js aren't completely static.

Comment: @zerkms imo it's not irrelevant to the future people who may find this question and answer, and that is what StackOverflow is largely about, I thought? It is also a point against using the method in this answer, which is why I state it. I've found it's useful to give as many points of information as you can - to aid others - rather than saving them up for that one exacting question to come along.

Comment: @pebbl: then your solution is XSS affected as well. For example `addEvent(document.getElementById('your_input')` - `your_input` may be taken from runtime. So it's a possible vulnerability. According to your strategy you should have also mentioned your code is potentially not secure as well, correct? Now it looks like you're blaming other person's solution though your one potentially has the same issue.

Comment: @zerkms No not by an inline event attack it isn't. My original point that you seem to be distorting somewhat, is that using the above method means you cannot strip inline events, without removing your own code. However, with the other answers on this page you can. If you assume with my code that is happening - as I would recommend - where is the attack vector?

Comment: @pebbl: Who even strips attributes from static HTML? It's a part of a template. "where is the attack vector" - I've given it in my previous comment. "However, with the other answers on this page you can" - now you're trying to present your solution as safe-by-definition, while others are vulnerable-by-definition. It's weird. All the three answers security depends on the developer and the particular code, and not on anything else. Giving false expectations about security is even worse than covering all the cases (especially irrelevant ones).

Comment: @zerkms Yes your comment that you edited and I only just saw the update. Your argument is rather weak tbh, and I can only think you are in a bad mood. If someone did manage to inject an element with a particular id all they would achieve is binding my events to their element. Hardly a problem. Whereas allowing access to `onload=""` `onclick=""` events can execute any javascript on the page... I'd hope you'd see the difference. Not many people would apply these measures on a static page, but you were the one to mention that.. I did not.

Comment: @pebbl: if page is completely static then both solutions are the same secure. If the name of the handler or id is determined in runtime then **both** solutions are the same affected. And then in **both** cases you need to apply some validation/sanitizing.

Comment: @zerkms I'm refering to the Markup Insertion part of XSS Vulnerabilities which can occur on dynamically generated pages (powered by any server-side scripting language, including JavaScript). This mainly concerns tags & inline event handlers. There are of course other security concerns to be aware of. I've mentioned the ones I see as significant, which is all I can do. If you believe my own answer to be thusly problematic you should comment with your arguments there. You seem to have disagreed heavily with only 1 of my points, there are 5 more, I trust you believe the others to be valid.

Comment: @pebbl: the others are valid, and XSS is totally irrelevant

Answer (score 3):

```
var addEvent = (function(){
  /// addEventListener works for all modern browsers
  if ( window.addEventListener ) {
    /// I'm returning a closure after the choice on which method to use
    /// has been made, so as not to waste time doing it for each event added.
    return function(elm, eventName, listener, useCapture){
      return elm.addEventListener(eventName,listener,useCapture||false);
    };
  }
  /// attachEvent works for Internet Explorer
  else if ( window.attachEvent ) {
    return function(elm, eventName, listener){
      /// IE expects the eventName to be onclick, onfocus, onkeydown (and so on)
      /// rather than just click, focus, keydown as the other browsers do.
      return elm.attachEvent('on'+eventName,listener);
    };
  }
})();
```

Using the above cross browser function you can then do the following (once the dom is fully loaded):

```
addEvent(document.getElementById('your_input'),'focus',function(e){
  var input = e.target || e.srcElement;
  alert('this input has gained focus!');
});
```

Comment: While I do appreciate this, it reminds me of times when another `else` branch was required - for _some_ browsers that didn't support `attachEvent`.

Comment: @raina77ow and you'll no doubt be reminded of similar occurances as we travel further into the future ;) it is the curse of the conscientious web developer unfortunately. However the current "modern" browsers are doing a far better job of following specs than before... so it occurs less often. One day we may be able to forget about IE8, but not quite yet imo..

Comment: And you're right, of course. ) My point (and it's more like a rant, I have to admit) is that it's a bit... unusual seeing clean JS providing cross-browsery - as this function should already be in the developer's toolkit. But then again, this dev obviously just starts to fill the one, so... disregard this comment. )

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("elementId").addEventListener("focus",function(e){
 //Do Something here
});
```

Comment: It might surprise you, but input can get a focus without a click.

Comment: Yup, hooking the 'focus' event would be a better bet.