# How to change input value onfocus and onblur (no jquery)

Tags: javascript, search, focus, field, placeholder

I wrote some code, kind of like an alternative for HTML5 placeholder using JavaScript, but it's not working. As far as I can figure (with my mediocre knowledge of js), everything should work, but it's not. Please help!!! Here's my code:

**JavaScript:**

```
(function(){
    var field = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    var placeholdertext = "Search box"; // << change this to whatever you want the placeholder text to be

    field.setAttribute("onblur", "if(value=='') { value = '" + placeholdertext + "'")
    field.setAttribute("onfocus", "if(value=='" + placeholdertext + "') { value = '' }")
})();
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="search" value="Search box" id="placeholder">
```

## Edit:

I don't want to use jQuery or inline-html-coding, please. Thanks for any help, guys!!!

Comment: Consider using the HTML5 [`placeholder`](http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder) attribute instead

Comment: ``kind of like an alternative for HTML5 placeholder using JavaScript``

Comment: @ModernDesigner - Consider using an [existing `placeholder` polyfill](https://github.com/jamesallardice/Placeholders.js) instead. You haven't considered things like the placeholder value being submitted with the form if the user hasn't entered a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `value` with `this.value` in your code (as you need to check the value of the element that triggers an event, and not some global variable) and it [will work](http://jsfiddle.net/FpFmv/).

As a sidenote, perhaps I'd prefer still using `placeholder` attribute here, providing a JS shim only for the browsers that don't support it. This would simplify the javascript code part too, as you wouldn't have to use some variable just to store some DOM-related data:

```
field.onblur = function() {
  if (this.value === '') {
    this.value = this.getAttribute('placeholder');
  }
};

field.onfocus = function() {
  if (this.value === this.getAttribute('placeholder') ) {
    this.value = '';
  }
};
```

... and in fact I'd prefer using `addEventListener/attachEvent` here instead of `onblur/onfocus`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13214985/1229023).

Comment: I looked at the fiddle and it did work!!! I put it on my page, but it's showing an error in Chrome (and additionally isn't working). Here's the error: ``Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call 'setAttribute' of null.``

Comment: @ModernDesigner It means your script gets invoked before `#placeholder` element is in DOM - and that, in turn, means the script probably resides in `<head>` section (and doesn't have `defer` attribute on). Either make it work `onLoad/onDOMReady` (in that fiddle it's exactly that), or move it to the end of `<body>`, or use `<defer>` (biting the [Opera bullet](http://caniuse.com/script-defer))

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="text" value="Enter The User Name" onblur="if(this.value == '') { this.style.color='#f00'; this.value='Enter The User Name'}" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Enter The User Name') {this.style.color='#000'; this.value=''}" />
```

Try This without Jquery

Answer (score 1):

Without jQuery:

```
field.onblur = function() {
  if (field.value == '') {
    field.value = placeholdertext;
  }
};

field.onfocus= function() {
  if (field.value == placeholdertext ) {
    field.value = '';
  }
};
```

Comment: I'd really recommend using `this.value` instead of `field.value` here as well.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but if i'm understanding your question this should work.  If it works don't forget to hit the check mark.

```
    var field = document.getElementById('placeholder');
    var placeholdertext = "Search box";

    field.bind('onblur', function() {
        if (field.text() === '') {
            field.text(placeholdertext);
        }
    });

    field.bind('onfocus', function() {
        if (field.text() === '') {
            field.text(placeholdertext);
        }
    });
```

Comment: I really don't think [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) is what you want to use here

Comment: What's the problem with binding the event to the element.

Comment: Also, `val()` is not a method of DOM elements

Comment: @JustinCase Perhaps you missed the *"no jquery"* part in the question title

Comment: distracted with football.  I usually just read the code.  my fault